# Did Hans Christian Oersted ever marry?

Tags: 19th-century, denmark

Did [Hans Christian Oersted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Christian_%C3%98rsted) ever marry, and if so, whom?

Google is really short on answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Danish wikipedia (http://da.wikipedia.org/wiki/H.C._Ørsted#Familieforhold) in my translation.

On the 17th of May 1814, Oersted married Inger Birgitte Ballum (28 March 1789 - 3 November 1875), daughter of pastor [minister, priest] N.R. Ballum, in Kjeldby on [the island] Møn. She had lost her father early in life. When they became engaged, she was a maid in the house of Oersted’s father, who had moved to Roskilde. He lived with her in a very happy marriage until his death. She is described as a woman with a light and vivacious personality, who managed her home with great skill and independence. They had seven children; three sons and four daughters.

Comment: Almost perfect translation, but Wikipedia claims he married in 1814.

Comment: You are right. I have edited the answer to correct the error.